# Thymeleaf special character conversion in Outlook

Tags: html, outlook, thymeleaf

I have following html code **(data coming in  the variable as UTF-8)**

```html
<p style="margin: 0; font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
Project Name:  <span th:text="${projectName}">ProjectName</span>
</p>
```

Any special character that  is in `${projectName}` , **for example :** "Carol's" is getting converted  to "Carol?s"   in Outlook mail. Anyway to  correct  this  in Thymeleaf ?

Comment: `?` will be picked when you convert a Unicode string to a single-byte encoding (and a certain source character is not supported in the target). Therefore the email you generate cannot be Unicode. Instead of concentrating on this character, try to find the setting that outputs the entire email in an undesired encoding.

Comment: Thanks !so  you  mean  the  default  encoding of the recipient's outlook?  and  put the  same encoding for the   email generated ?

Comment: Well, are you *sure* the email body goes out in the correct encoding? Have you looked a the actual bytes that are being produced? Outlook can deal with Unicode emails, my suspicion was that the server puts the question mark there.